# Can it possibly work if I assign two shells to SHELL in cron?

Tags: shell, cron, environment-variables

Recently I started the process of gradual switching my shell to [nu](https://github.com/nushell/nushell)
and because of it I thought about assigning its path to SHELL in cron.

Having read a good part of the manual at `man 5 crontab`, I took a look at PATH and copied the convention of using `:` in between the values attempting to assign two shells to SHELL:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash:/home/jerzy/.cargo/bin/nu
```

It does not work, the scripts from my crontab are not doing their job. Whereas either `SHELL=/bin/bash` and
`SHELL=/home/jerzy/.cargo/bin/nu` works fine.

Can I assign two shells to SHELL? Does it even make sense to do so?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by this?

Comment: @Gordon Nu does not yet support many features available in Bash, as  multiline commands with `\\` . I was hoping that in such case Bash would handle them.

Comment: Have you considered just having each entry directly call a script that does what you desire? Provided you have a proper `#!` line at the start of the script and the script file is executable, the shell configured in `cron` simply does not matter.

Comment: @Austin I have. Most of my entries are already scripted, not all, though.

Comment: The `:` separator is specific to environment variables which take **lists**, like `PATH` and a few similar variables (`NODE_PATH`,  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`...), where there is a simple test to try different items of the list in order: does the file we're looking for exist in that directory or not?

Comment: @JerzyBrzóska How do you think that would work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, having multiple shells in `SHELL` doesn't make sense, for the reasons [@Stephen described in their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/657805/170373). But, the `SHELL` variable only controls the shell `cron` uses to run the immediate command part in the `crontab` line; and at least in Vixie cron, which you often have on Linux systems, `SHELL` can be changed in the middle of `crontab`. The [Debian man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/cron/crontab.5.en.html) for `crontab(5)` says:

> The crontab file is parsed from top to bottom, so any environment settings will affect only the cron commands below them in the file.

That sentence looks like it might have been added by Debian, but it seems to work the same on the CentOS system I tried. But as noted in comments by Toby Speight, environment variable assignments in `crontab` aren't a POSIX feature at all, so YMMV.

---

So, regardless of the cron, you should be able to do something like this:

```
* * * * * /path/to/somescript.py maybe 
* * * * * /path/to/otherscript.pl some
* * * * * /path/to/thirdscript.sh args
```

where the scripts have the proper hashbang lines, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python3`, `#!/usr/bin/perl`, `#!/bin/bash` or whatever. `SHELL` just needs to be set to something that can take `/path/to/somescript.py maybe` etc. as a command and run that script with an argument. Most shells support the trivial stuff identically, so if you put the complicated stuff inside separate scripts and keep the `crontab` lines simple, you can use whatever shell or scripting language in the scripts themselves.

---

And, if you need to use different shells in the immediate crontab commands, you can do this, at least in Vixie cron:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * 8-14 * * if test "$(date +\%w)" = 0; then echo $BASH_VERSION > /tmp/bashtest; fi
SHELL=/usr/bin/fish
* * 8-14 * * if test (date +\%w) = 0; echo $FISH_VERSION > /tmp/fishtest; end
```

Both check if the day is Sunday, and print the shell version if it is, one using Bash, one using fish. (That's only an example, of course, but because of the way the cron time settings work, running on the first/second/last particular weekday of a month is one of the common cases where you might want to use shell code on the crontab command.)

Also, as an aside, you mentioned in the comments that Nu doesn't support multiline commands with `\`, and was hoping you could use Bash there. Note that you can't have multiline commands in the crontab line: The command itself must be on just one line in the file, and while `cron` takes a `%` sign as a line break, the lines following the first are sent to the standard input of the command. (And that's why we need to escape the `%` used in the format string for `date` above.)

Comment: Is it specified that `SHELL=` lines can be used multiple times like that?  That it works for you might just be a feature (or implementation artefact) of the particular `cron` you used.  Of course, one can always use a shell itself as the command to run. (e.g. `/bin/bash -c 'if test …'`)

Comment: @TobySpeight yes.  You can use intersped "mailto=" lines to send the output of anything in the following section to different recipients, too.

Comment: @TobySpeight, for Vixie cron, at least the [Debian man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/cron/crontab.5.en.html) says that _"The crontab file is parsed from top to bottom, so any environment settings will affect only the cron commands below them in the file."_.  That sentence might be a Debian addition, but it works the same on the ancient CentOS system I tried on. If there's other implementations that do it differently, I don't know.

Comment: It seems that assignment lines are all extensions to the POSIX syntax, so there cannot be any formal spec for this that covers all implementations ("_In the POSIX locale, the user or application shall ensure that a crontab entry is a text file consisting of lines of six fields each._" - [`crontab`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html)).

Answer (score 25):

No, you can’t assign two shells to `SHELL`: `cron` needs to know which shell to start, there can only be one. The `SHELL` variable in `crontab` doesn’t specify *possible* shells, it specifies *the* shell to use. `cron` reads the value in `SHELL`, if any, and uses that as the command to run; it doesn’t interpret `:` or any other symbol.

A fallback can’t work either: if something fails with `nu`, `cron` can’t know whether it failed because of `nu` or something else. Most scripts are written for a given interpreter (specified in their shebang), you can’t try running them with one and again with another. Likewise, `crontab` entries are written with the specified `SHELL` in mind (if not the default `/bin/sh`).